# Flex/Flash Builder - Copy/paste MULTIPLE rows from one dataGrid to another

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

I'm in need of help! Basically I have two mx DataGrids, one that pulls in data from an xml file and the other is blank because I'd like to add to it. I'm trying to select multiple rows from one grid and add them to the other by clicking a button.

Currently I'm successfully able to select, copy and paste one row, but no more. The allowMultipleSelection option is set to true, however when I select multiple rows and try to paste them into the empty dataGrid, it will only paste one row at a time.

Here's the function that I'm using to add the selected row to the empty datagrid.

```
        public function handleAddRow(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            summaryGrid.dataProvider.addItem({"Category": offersGrid.selectedItem.category, 
                "Program": offersGrid.selectedItem.program, 
                "Manufacturer": offersGrid.selectedItem.manufacturer, 
                "Products": offersGrid.selectedItem.products, 
                "MinimumOrder": offersGrid.selectedItem.minimumOrder, 
                "OfferDetail": offersGrid.selectedItem.offerDetail
                }); 


        }
```

Thanks in advance! 
--Moe

Comment: One solution is loop upto your dataprovider length and add all selected rows to new new dataprovider.

Answer (score 0):

use the selectedCells property instead selectedItem. This is a collection of Object which contain all the selected rows.

```
function handleAddRow(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for each(var row in offersGrid.selectedCells) 
        summaryGrid.dataProvider.addItem({
            "Category": row.category, 
            "Program": row.program, 
            "Manufacturer": row.manufacturer, 
            "Products": row.products, 
            "MinimumOrder": row.minimumOrder, 
            "OfferDetail": row.offerDetail
         });
}
```

Try with this and be sure this fields are in your grid.

```
function handleAddRow(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for each(var row in offersGrid.selectedCells) 
        summaryGrid.dataProvider.addItem({
            category: row.category, 
            program: row.program, 
            manufacturer: row.manufacturer, 
            products: row.products, 
            minimumOrder: row.minimumOrder, 
            offerDetail: row.offerDetail
         });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm getting an error 1119: Access of possibly undefined property selectedCells through a reference with static type mx.controls:DataGrid. Is this because my Datagrid is an mx component?

Comment: I changed it to an advancedDataGrid and now the error messages are gone. It's adding the amount of selected cells to the datagrid, but the rows are blank.

Comment: Ok... I have an idea wath must be, but I don't have flex rigth now so i cant verify it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance, but it still didn't work. It just copies blank entries.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to invoke `addItem` on all the selected items. Here is the code I have tried and it works fine:

```
public function handleAddRow(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
                var selectedItems:Array = offersGrid.selectedItems;
                if(summaryGrid.dataProvider == null) summaryGrid.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection();
                for each(var item:CategoryObject in offersGrid.selectedItems) {
                    (summaryGrid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection).addItem(item);
                }
        }
```

You may need to make any minor change as per your requirement. If you face any other issue drop a comment.